# How to change unittest.TestResult to disable/remove traceback on Failures?

Tags: python, unit-testing, stack-trace, python-unittest, traceback

I am using `unittest` for UI testing and [HTMLTestRunner](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB8QFjAAahUKEwjd89St3IXGAhWIC5IKHc4pAeI&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftungwaiyip.info%2Fsoftware%2FHTMLTestRunner.html&ei=SX14VZ2rCIiXyATO04SQDg&usg=AFQjCNFZ005B5-JSluouaXnDXRL9U12P_g&bvm=bv.95039771,d.aWw) to publish test reports. 
To have more neat reports, I want to remove/disable traceback on output. I found `sys.tracebacklimit = 0` effective but it just works on **Errors** and apparenty error stack is separate from failure stack in unittest.TestResult. How can I have traceback removed from failures as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed HTMLTestRunner `addError` and `addFailure` and replaces `_exc_str` with `" "`. Also you can replace it with any desired string.